# Stop color hilighting of selected item in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I am using combo box in WinForm but when i was selected any item in combo box then selected item background color is blue. i want to remove this blue background color (particularly on form load, tried to set focus to other control in the form, but combo highlight not removed) but item should be selected .

Can anybody help out on this...?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just set the selected index to -1, but it's been awhile.

Comment: but item should be selected...

Comment: Are you using a special color theme on windows?? that should not happens on a common combination. Try removing that combo and adding a new one. @asawyer that will clear the combo, but that's not what OP is asking ;)

Comment: @Dhana I see, sorry I missed that. I suppose you could always override the rendering and paint the thing yourself. Then it's any color you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the only way to do this is by subclassing the combobox control.

Here is an example where someone does that:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002/

There are probably more on the web to guide you.

Comment: Given link explains how to show tooltip when mouse is hovering over combobox item. It is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the same I have tried almost EVERYTHING:

- setting the `DropdownStyle` property to DropdownList
- `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { comboBox1.Select(0, 0); }));`
- `combobox1.SelectionLength = 0;`
- changing `comboBox.TabIndex`
- Not tried `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");` because it is not a reliable solution

Nothing helped. Maybe because I don't have text in my combobox items, only images.
The only stable and working solution was to move a focus on another Label control:

```
    label.Focus();
```

You could also hide that label.

Answer (score 2):

I found something over [this site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_25070779.html)

Create a timer and enable it in your SelectedIndexChanged event, and in the timer just add `ComboBox1.Select(0,0)` this should remove the selection part and then disable the timer. Identify other entry points where in you can `Enable` the timer again

Code snippet

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the item selected in the combobox
    ComboBox cbx = (ComboBox)sender;
    int idx = cbx.SelectedIndex;    
    string s1 = cbx.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // Enable the time so that the Highlight can be removed
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the Highlight
    comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
    // Disable timer
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: comboBox1.Select(0, 0) -- not works since combobox is 'dropdownlist' not editable text allowed..,

Comment: @Dhana Then does setting `comboBox1.SelectionLength=0` work ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big VB user, and only play with it in Excel, but also had this problem when a selection was made in my ComboBox.  I finally found a way to get rid of the blue text highlighting.

I have a ComboBox on a UserForm.  By selecting the ComboBox and viewing the Properties, simply changing the 'HideSelection' to True worked for me.  You could also code for it:
ComboBox1.HideSelection = True

Comment: This is the correct solution. Although your answer is about VBA, it is the same for WinForms with C# and VB.NET. You need to set the `HideSelection` property to `true`. Strange, though; that should be the default.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I can find no `HideSelection` property for a ComboBox in Windows Forms. It exists for TextBoxBase and the controls that inherit from it, but ComboBox does not. Which is a shame, as I would really like one! (I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5)

Comment: @jonp Hmm, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that comment several years ago. Presumably it had worked for me at the time. I thought maybe ComboBox just hides the base class method, but a quick look at the Reference Source suggests that it doesn't even have the same hierarchy as TextBox. It actually inherits from ListControl, which inherits from Control. So there is no hidden property to set. Perhaps you can get at the underlying TextBox control, although .NET doesn't provide any managed way of doing so. You'll have to use P/Invoke to get the handle. ...

Comment: Ask a new question, or place a bounty on this one if you need a full solution. Although I have to wonder why anyone would really need this. In all the comboboxes I've seen, hiding the selection is the default. Any selection that has been made disappears when focus leaves the combobox control. That's all the HideSelection property does. As I said before, it is the default for textbox and combobox controls. If you do ask a new question, be sure to elaborate on what makes your situation different. @jonp

Comment: @Cody I didn't say I needed to set it true; I need to set it false! My Find / Replace function selects the found text to highlight it and then shows a dialog asking if you want to replace this occurrence, which loses focus on the ComboBox and the highlighting disappears. I will ask a new question if I can't resolve it some other way (I feel that people are too quick to ask questions on this forum, they need to try a bit harder first!)

Answer (score 1):

There is an Easy solution for you

```
private void myComboBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     myComboBoxComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: wouldn't this take down the selection?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way just Disable the ComboBox and then enable it

```
combobox.Enabled = false;
combobox.Enabled = true;
```

and even you select an item inside it the item will still selected but the highlight will go

Comment: ^^^This is exactly the solution people are looking for. Top answer in my book.  Thank you^^^

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and after not finding a working solution I had the same idea as @Vadim K.

Here is a short example.

First step is to to change focus in the UI_Load event.

```
Private Sub UI_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    Me.lblTitle.Focus()
End Sub
```

Next step is to handle the case when someone selects a new value

```
Private Sub comboExportDates_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comboExportDates.SelectedIndexChanged
        Me.lblTitle.Focus()
End Sub
```

Works fine for me